# Push from Android to Outlook Web App

Tags: outlook, android, synchronization, outlook-on-the-web

Is it possible to sync the Outlook Web App with an Android device in both directions?

With a standard outlook.com account, the synchronisation from the Outlook Web App to the Android device works well. However, the Android device cannot push informations to the Outlook Web App.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution after more searches ...

Use an Exchange account with this configuration :

- **Domain\User :** Full email adress (e.g. : john.doe@outlook.com)
- **Server name :** s.outlook.com
- **Other :** Works with SSL on ports 443 and 993

Then, everything will be syncable